# Do you gain a set bonus when using two of the same item from a set?

Tags: diablo-iii

In other words, is it necessary to use two different items from a set in order to get the bonus?

For example, here is the [Hallowed Avenger](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/hallowed-avenger) hand crossbow from the Hallowed Armaments set. Since it is a hand crossbow, it is only usable by demon hunters. The only other non-class specific items in the set are a shield and an axe. It seems odd to me that if you plan on using the Hallowed Avenger, you would need to pair it with a shield or axe to get the bonus. Can you use two Hallowed Avengers and get the bonus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot gain set bonuses for wearing 2 of the same set item because you would be unable to equip them. Set items are unique equipped as shown in the picture. You are unable to equip two of the same one.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Description of the item will tell you what you need to wear to get the set bonus.

But AFAIK you cannot wear two same legendary/set items at the same time anyways, in the bottom right corner it says "unique equipped".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anyone has been able to find out yet, but In Diablo 2, you did not get set bonuses for wearing multiple identical pieces of a set (eg rings or weapons), as [mentioned in another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/32644/if-i-use-2-identical-set-rings-and-add-a-different-set-piece-will-i-get-the-bon).

Therefore I'd imagine the same rule would apply here, and you would not get the bonuses.

Comment: I suspect that it works that way too, but I'm looking for a confirmation from someone with two of the same set piece that can test it out. Thanks for the response, though!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in the item description (with the verbose option checked in the menu) 
it will tell you exactly what you need to trigger additional bonuses.

Two of the same item will most likely not give you the bonus unless it lists the specific item twice in the set description.